# Вывод строки много раз JS

Tags: javascript

Нужно
Нужно введенную строку вывести 10 раз, заранее спасибо!

```
  $("#brend").change(function(){
    var brend = $("#brend").val();
    brand = $(".rozigr-brand").text(brend);
    var count = 10;
    var result = new Array(count + 1).join(brand);
    console.log(result);
});
```

Сейчас выводит [object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#brend").change(function() {
  var brend = $("#brend").val();
  $(".rozigr-brand").text(brend);
  var count = 10;
  var result = Array(count).fill(brend).join('');
  console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input typ="text" id="brend" />
<div class="rozigr-brand"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Переменная `brand` (необъявленная, кстати) у тебя содержит объект `jQuery` - его возвращает метод `text()` при наличии аргумента. Поэтому, в консоль и выводится "[object Object]".

А вообще, стоило сделать примерно так:

```js
$('#brand').change(function () {
  const brand = this.value;
  $('.raffle-brand').text(brand);
  console.log(brand.repeat(10));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="brand">
<p class="raffle-brand"></p>
```